# jQuery ajaxFileUpload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using `ajaxFileUpload` along with codeigniter for uploading image.If I browse the image,image uploaded. After upload the image I am showing the image along with an cancel button `(#cancel)` after the image. I wrote code for cancel button,it deletes the image from server.It is working properly. But after canceling the image the whole process is not working as first time.

The code is like below

```
$(function() {    
   $('#item_photo_uload').change(function(e) 
   {   
       e.preventDefault();       
       $.ajaxFileUpload({
         url            :site_url+'/menu/upload_file',
         secureuri      :false,
         fileElementId  :'item_photo_uload',
         dataType       :'json',
         success  : function (data,status)
         {             
            if(data.status != 'error')
            {
               $('#one_file').html('<img src="'+base_url+'assets/images/item_photo/'+data.file_name+'" height="50" width="100"/><img id="cancel" title="Cancel This Image" src="'+base_url+'assets/images/item_photo/cancel.png"/>' );

                $('#cancel').click(function()
                {
                  if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this file?'))
                    {
                        $.post(site_url+'/menu/delete_file',{file_name: data.file_name},function(data)
                        {
                            if(data)
                            {
                                $('#one_file').html('');                                
                                $("#item_photo_uload").prop('disabled', false);
                                $("#item_photo_uload").val("");   

                            }
                        });    
                    }
                });             
             }
         }            
      });

      $("#item_photo_uload").val("");         
      $("#item_photo_uload").prop('disabled', true);

      return false;
   });
});
```

Here `#one_file` is a div to show the image, `#item_photo_uload` is the input field for browsing the file.

Comment: I imagine this has something to do with it: ` $('#item_photo_uload').change(function(e)` - this will only trigger if the element changes value. I think when you click cancel, something is happening to prevent this function from binding again. Do you think you could add an `alert` into your code to see if it keeps firing when you try and upload new images?

Comment: @RichPeck Thanks for your reply. I tried the alert and alert is not firing when I try to upload new image. I think I have to refresh the input type file field or I have to use .bind() method of jQuery.

Comment: Hmmm maybe we should make `$(document).on("change", "#item_photo_uload", function() {`

Comment: Although I think the real problem is the `change` function

Comment: The change event is sent to an element when its value changes. This event is limited to <input> elements, <textarea> boxes and <select> elements. For select boxes, checkboxes, and radio buttons, the event is fired immediately when the user makes a selection with the mouse, but for the other element types the event is deferred until the element loses focus - http://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: @RichPeck - I tried a lot but failed. Have you any solution ?? I tried like below.

$('#item_photo_uload').on("change",function(e) 
   { 


Would you like to suggest other than this??


Thanks for reply

Comment: Have you tried `$(document).on("change", "#item_photo_uload", function() {` ?

Comment: Thanks for reply. Do I replace `$(function() {` with your `$(document).on("change", "#item_photo_uload", function() ` ??

I tried but its not working. Thanks